# How to increase the printed number of columns in python?

Tags: python, arrays

For columns more than 5, python prints columns in next line for the same row. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.rand(5,8)
>>> x
array([[ 0.1842756 ,  0.09323525,  0.2910024 ,  0.57115116,  0.6894235 ,
         0.97366307,  0.32833171,  0.870427  ],
       [ 0.47993437,  0.01394924,  0.83829772,  0.03822534,  0.01289683,
         0.61385652,  0.38680997,  0.15549481],
       [ 0.12124796,  0.14482983,  0.41347171,  0.02592663,  0.21083298,
         0.16138967,  0.93531758,  0.51078627],
       [ 0.25442897,  0.82625412,  0.90589188,  0.1533367 ,  0.12980143,
         0.89043485,  0.36364293,  0.54288548],
       [ 0.08695784,  0.03753765,  0.50422536,  0.08978102,  0.89556966,
         0.48192554,  0.23764354,  0.65701369]])
```

The screen has more space for printing columns, for example up to 10. How to make columns printed on the same line?

Is it possible to avoid `pandas` for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Set NumPy's print options:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

```
numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=whatever)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add this comment as default setting for `python`? Something like `startup.m` file in `Matlab`?

Comment: @SathishKrishnan: [It's possible to set an interactive startup file](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/appendix.html#the-interactive-startup-file) that'll be run at the start of any interactive session, and IPython probably has its own, more powerful capabilities for that. While it's technically possible to set a file that will be run at the start of any Python program, doing so is a terrible idea and a debugging nightmare.